# could not import data_manager_service/utils (cannot find package "data_manager_service/utils" in GOROOT or GOPATH)

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have set my `GOPATH` to `/Users/didi/go` and am currently working in the folder path `/Users/didi/go/src/route-data-manager-service`. However, I am encountering an error when attempting to import a package (see the provided error image).

```
cannot find package "data_manager_service/utils" in GOROOT or GOPATH
```

Based on the `GOPATH` package dependency mechanism, shouldn't the package be searched from `$GOPATH/src/projectName/src` by default? I am using Visual Studio Code and Go version 1.20.

Comment: Use modules, read and follow go.dev/doc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a small example to show how to achieve your needs. As a premise, follow the suggestion provided by @Volker in the comment because you need to fully understand that part before being proficient with Go.
Now, let's get back to the example. I'll provide a quick step-by-step guide to help you start with the project. The steps are:

1. Create a folder named `importpackages` on the file system
2. Enter the folder within your terminal and issue the command `code . -r` to open it in VSCode
3. Issue the command `go mod init mymodule` to initialize a Go module called `mymodule`
4. Create a subfolder called `mypackage` within the `importpackages` one. Your relative path should be `./importpackages/mypackage`
5. Create a file at the following path `./importpackages/mypackage/util.go` with the following content:

   ```golang
   package mypackage

   func DoSomething() string {
       return "mypackage - DoSomething()"
   }
   ```
6. Create a file at the following path `./importpackages/main.go` with the following content:

   ```golang
   package main

   import (
       "fmt"
       "mymodule/mypackage" // this is the statement you need to reference other local-defined pkg
   )

   func main() {
       fmt.Println("we're invoking a function from another pkg...")
       fmt.Println(mypackage.DoSomething())
   }
   ```
7. Within the folder `./importpackages` issue the command `go run .` to execute the program. You should see two statements printed out on the terminal.

Let me know if this helps you solve your issue, thanks!